# With Facebook API, can I see my answers to the questions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to see how I was answering questions, asked in some Facebook group I am a member of. Is there a way to do it with the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the [question_option_votes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/question_option_votes/) fql table.

However you need to have the appropriate permissions to do so:

```
To read options from the question_option table you need the following permissions:

    user_questions for questions posed by the current user.
    friends_questions for questions posed by friends of the current user.
```

I doubt that, unless your an admin of that group, you would not be able to get that data.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps:

**First:**

your application need permission to user_questions and user_groups

**Second:**

you can use a multi-query to get all yours questions, answer and voters with basic information.

**Third:**

Use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to check the data

**And the end, use this query:**

```
fql?q={

    "questions":"select id,question from question where owner= me()",

    "options":"select id, question_id, name,votes from question_option WHERE question_id in (select id from #questions)",

    "option_votes":"select voter_id, option_id  from question_option_votes where option_id IN (select id from #options) order by voter_id desc",

    "users":"select uid, name, first_name, middle_name, last_name, sex, locale, pic_small_with_logo, pic_big_with_logo, pic_square_with_logo, pic_with_logo, username from user where uid IN (select voter_id from #option_votes)"
}
```

**Note:** the fields "uid, name, first_name, middle_name, last_name, sex, locale, pic_small_with_logo, pic_big_with_logo, pic_square_with_logo, pic_with_logo, username" is public access and don't need a token